# "webSocketFailed" with no Listeners registered in react native

Tags: react-native

I have touchable ListView and other touchable Buttons on my View. 
Those are working fine in Simulator, But When I run app in device, I get this error -

tid:main][RCTEventEmitter.m:52] Sending `websocketFailed` with no listeners registered.

And, touch events are not working.

Anybody know what is the issue ?

FYI - I am using TouchableHighlight and TouchableOpacity

Comment: Do you have debugging enabled in the dev menu by chance? Try disabling it: http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html

Comment: This issue still persists with React Native version 0.39. at iOS 10.1.1 Any news? Are you also getting loads of error messages related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10027 ? None of the suggested solutions there work for me..

Comment: This looks like a race condition [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9f3e928f8335a51cd87593a150726e564afd2fa4/Libraries/WebSocket/WebSocket.js#L86-L87). Can you check if swapping these two lines works for you? It worked for me for some other case. Going to send a PR soon.

Comment: any solution for that ?